# CI REST Server Api Key only works on GET Method

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter, web-services

I'm using  [CI REST Server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver). But I have problem with `X-API-KEY`. This key only works for GET method. How can I do it for PUT, POST and DELETE?

For GET method I just use this code:

```
function index(){
    $data['dataKontak'] = json_decode($this->curl->simple_get($this->api.'/kontak?x-api-key=12345'));
    $this->load->view('kontak/list', $data);
}
```

This is my code for other methods:

```
function create(){
    $insert = $this->curl->simple_post($this->api.'/kontak', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10));
}

function edit(){
    $update = $this->curl->simple_put($this->api.'/kontak', $data, array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10));
}

function delete($id){
    $delete = $this->curl->simple_delete($this->api.'/kontak?'.$this->auth, array('id'=> $id), array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10));
}
```

Comment: Is there any error? Maybe the api you are calling is for `GET` method only.

Comment: the error was not detected, maybe like not connected to API.

Comment: It's more likely the API you are calling is on `GET` method. or else, you can check if your key is validated for all methods.

Comment: if I check on postman, all working fine.